# Pytorch - building from source - CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH

Tags: pytorch

I am building PyTorch from source as my GPU card is not supported by the packages in pip or conda.

I am in `Ubuntu 20.04`. I followed the instructions at :

I get this error. I searched the internet but there are no useful pointers.

There are numerous errors like below:

```
CMake Error at modules/observers/CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_library):
  The install of the caffe2_observers target requires changing an RPATH from
  the build tree, but this is not supported with the Ninja generator unless
  on an ELF-based platform.  The CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH variable may
  be set to avoid this relinking step.
```

Any idea how this could be resolved. I already tried setting up an environment variable as below but it did not help.

```
$ export CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=On
$ echo ${CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH}
On
```

Comment: In the question, after "I followed the instructions at" the actual link is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that installing cmake solves the problem.

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

I could not debug why it worked. I was in ubuntu version 20.04. May be it had a `cmake` that was too old and running the above command fetches the latest version.

I thought this is still a useful information for someone facing the same issues - so, noting down here.

Comment: The error message in the question comes from cmake. Therefore some cmake was already installed and this answer does not make much sense. Possibly the version was too low, but the answer does not tell.

Comment: This worked for me. However, when I reinstalled CMake using apt, I also had to delete the PyTorch repo and do the whole thing again for it to work. I guess this might have something to do with CMake cache.

Comment: @SomaSiddhartha after reinstalling CMake, simply deleting the `CMakeCache.txt` and re-running the CMake step would have sufficed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for receiving this error can be that there's no tool installed that is capable of changing the `RPATH`, such as `chrpath`.

Installing such a tool (e.g. via `sudo apt install chrpath`), deleting the `CMakeCache.txt` from the build folder and then re-running CMake should fix the issue in this case.